# How to open Quick list in Intellij Idea

Tags: intellij-idea

Maybe do I do something wrong, but I can't open Idea's Quick list. I tried do that on Intellij 12 on Windows and 13, 14 on Linux by assigning shortcut, search action, search everywhere with no luck...
No action when I'm trying open it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to create Quick List in **File | Settings | Appearance and Behavior | Quick Lists** and then it would appear in **File | Settings | Appearance and Behavior | Keymap** where you can define a shortcut for it.

---

### [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtoAw.png]

### [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNvrV.png]

### [image: i.stack.imgur.com/CPTDF.png]